# Is every function from $W^{1,1}([0,1])$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am starting to learn about Sobolev spaces. I am trying to understand first a bit better what $W^{1,1}(I)$ is where $I=[0,1]$. I was wondering if every function in this space has to be continuous.

Comment: For every $u \in W^{1,p}$ there exists an absolute continuous function  $\hat u \colon I \to \overline {\mathbb R}$ such that $u=\hat u$ almost everywhere

Comment: I see. Then since elements of $W^{1,1}(I)$ are in particular functions in $L^1([0,1])$ we can choose a representative that is continuous everywhere right?

Comment: Yes, every function $u \in W^{1,p}$ has a (unique) continuous representative: there exists a continuous function $\hat u$ such that $\hat u$ belongs to the equivalence class of $u$ (under the relation of $z=w$ a.e.)

Comment: okay thanks, I get it now

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos where can I look that up sir?

Comment: @MackeyTopology A classic book is Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations by Brezis