# Representation of function in $W^{1,2}([-1,1])$ by function in $W^{1,2}_0([-1,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

I read some notes from a lecture, where it is claimed that
any function $\varphi \in W^{1,2}([-1,1])$ can be represented by
$$\varphi(x)= \psi(x) +c_1e^{x}+c_2 e^{-x}$$
where $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\psi\in W^{1,2}_0([-1,1])$.

Mabye someone can help me clarifying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that any element in $\varphi \in W^{1,2}([-1,1])$ is Hölder continuous, in particular, continuous up to the boundary. Let $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ solve
$$
\begin{pmatrix}e & e^{-1} \\ e^{-1} & e \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \varphi(1) \\ \varphi(-1) \end{pmatrix},
$$
which we can always solve uniquely since $\det (M)=e^2-e^{-2} \neq 0$ .Note that, by plugging in the boundary values, you also have
$$
T(\varphi-c_1e^x-c_2e^{-x})=0,
$$
where $T$ is the trace operator. Hence
$$
\psi=\varphi-c_1e^x-c_2e^{-x} \in W^{1,2}_0([-1,1]),
$$
since $T \psi=0$, and rearranging yields your desired identity.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have some homework to do :D

Comment: You are welcome. This is just a really fancy way of "subtracting boundary values".

Comment: Just to make sure If I could follow you. So we basically using $W_{0}^{1,2}([-1,1])=\lbrace u \in W^{1,2}([-1,1]) | Tu=0\rbrace$ and that $Tu= u\vert_{\partial[-1,1]}$ since $u \in W^{1,2}([-1,1])$ is a.e. continuous according to that post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928184/is-every-function-from-w1-10-1-continuous#comment10101770_3928184 and determine the constants accordingly such that $\psi$ disapears on the boundary. Right? But are you sure $c_1, c_2$ is calculated right? How is $\varphi(1)-\varphi(1)e-\varphi(-1)e^{-1}=0=\varphi(-1)-\varphi(1)e^{-1}-\varphi(-1)e^{1}$?

Comment: You are right on all accounts and thanks for pointing out my mistake. I think I salvaged the proof. Please double check again, if something is still wrong, feel free to unaccept this answer.